# Convergence in distribution for $\frac{Y}{\sqrt{\lambda}}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, central-limit-theorem

Given a sequence of independent r.v's $\{X_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ such that

$P(X_n=x)=\frac{1}{2}$ if $x=-1$ and/or $x=1$

Let $N\in Po(\lambda)$ be independent of $\{X_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ and we set that $Y=X_1+X_2+\dots+X_N$

One have to show that $\frac{Y}{\sqrt{\lambda}}$ converges in distribution to $N(0,1)$ as $\lambda$ goes to infinity.

How can this be shown? I have been thinking of some kind of use of central limit theorem but I don't get any idea for how to use it to show the convergence...

Comment: You might want to compute the characteristic function, the result follows.

Comment: With that done: $\varphi_X(t)=\frac{1}{2}e^{-it}+\frac{1}{2}e^{it}$ and $N$ we have, $\varphi_N(t)=e^{^{(\lambda e^{it}}-1)}$ But I don't see any pattern...

Comment: Thus $\varphi_X(t)=\cos t$. And you want $\varphi_Y$...

Comment: $\varphi_Y(t)=(\varphi_X(t))^N$ where $N$ is Poisson distributed..

Comment: No. Note that $\varphi_Y(t)$ is a (deterministic) number while $\varphi_X(t)^N$ is a random variable.

Comment: Hmm well i that case: $\varphi_Y(t)=\varphi_N(\varphi_X(t))=e^{\lambda(e^{icos(t)}-1)}$. Where does this lead...? :)

Comment: $\varphi_Y(t)\ne\varphi_N(\varphi_X(t))$. You need to be more careful (are you actually writing down these computations in full? you should...).

Comment: Hm, are you sure, Since $Y$ is sum of $X_i$'s up to $N$ and $N\in Po(\lambda)$ Shouldn't the formula hold? (composition formula)

Comment: Yes I am sure. $E[\varphi_X(t)^N]\ne\varphi_N(\varphi_X(t))$.

Comment: Should i "use" $N$ as deterministic? Such that say $N=n$ and then power of $n$ for the char.function case?

Comment: Simply stick to the definitions. What is $E[s^N]$? Hence what is $E[\varphi_X(t)^N]$?

Comment: Well... What is going on?

Answer (score 3):

The characteristic function of $Y$ is 
$\varphi_Y(t)=\mathbb{E}[\varphi_X(t)^N]=\mathbb{E}[\cos(t)^N]=e^{\lambda(\cos(t)-1)},$
and so the characteristic function of $Y/\sqrt{\lambda}$ converges, as $\lambda\to\infty$, 
$$\varphi_{Y/\sqrt{\lambda}}(t)=e^{\lambda(\cos(t/\sqrt{\lambda})-1)}\to e^{-t^2/2}=\varphi_{N(0,1)}(t).$$

Comment: I was going to post a solution with the computations. Perhaps they could help to clear any confusion.

Comment: Good idea. No harm in having two versions; one less detailed and one more detailed.

Comment: Added the post. Cheers,

Answer (score 3):

First show the independence hypotheses imply that $\Bbb E(e^{itY}\mid N=k)=\varphi_X(t)^k$. This means that $\Bbb E(e^{itY}\mid N)=\varphi_X(t)^N$. Then $\Bbb E(e^{itY})=\Bbb E(\Bbb E(e^{itY}\mid N))=\Bbb E(\varphi_X(t)^N)$, as noted by Didier in the comments. Finally $$\Bbb E(s^N)=\sum_{k\geqslant 0} s^k P(N=k)=\sum_{k\geqslant 0} s^k e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}=e^{\lambda(s-1)}$$

gives $\varphi_Y(t)=e^{\lambda(\cos t-1)}$. The rest follows by Byron's answer, since $\cos t =1-\dfrac{t^2}2+o(t^2)$.