# Proof of Poisson theorem using characteristic function

Tags: probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems

Suppose, $\lbrace X_n\rbrace_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence of random variables with distribution $B(n, p_n)$, and $\lim_{n\to\infty} np_n = \lambda > 0$, then $X_n \rightarrow X$ in distribution, where $X$ has $Poi(\lambda)$ distribution.

I want to prove it using characteristic function, so for each $n$

$\phi_{X_n}(t) = (p_ne^{it} + (1-p_n))^n$, but I don't know how to prove, that

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\phi_{X_n}(t) = \exp{\lambda(e^{it} - 1)}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show convergence in distribution, you only need to show pointwise convergence of the sequence of characteristic functions.

So fix any $t_0 \in \mathbb{R}$. For any $n \geq 1$, we have
$$
\phi_{X_n}(t_0) = (p_ne^{it_0} + (1-p_n))^n
= e^{n \ln \left( p_ne^{it_0} + (1-p_n) \right)}
= e^{n \ln \left( 1+  p_n(e^{it_0}-1) \right)}
$$
Now, since by assumption $p_n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0$ (as $n p_n  \to \lambda$), then $p_n(e^{it_0}-1)\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0$ and  we can do a first-order Taylor expansion of the logarithm. Specifically, when $n\to\infty$ we have
$$
\phi_{X_n}(t_0) = e^{n\left( p_n(e^{it_0}-1) + o(p_n) \right)}
= e^{n p_n(e^{it_0}-1) + o(n p_n)}
\underbrace{=}_{(\ast)} e^{\lambda(e^{it_0}-1 + o(1))}
\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 
e^{\lambda(e^{it_0}-1)}
$$
where for $(\ast)$ we used the fact that by assumption $np_n = \lambda + o(1)$ when $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Thank you for your help :)

Comment: You're welcome! This is a quite standard proof — you may find several variants here and there to practice and make sure you fully internalized it. (a quick search on this website yields, e.g. [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/620875/convergence-in-distribution-for-fracy-sqrt-lambda?rq=1) and [that](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1076708/convergence-to-n0-1-in-distribution).)

Comment: @Maciej By the way, if this fully answered your question, consider accepting the answer by clicking on the green $\color{green}\checkmark$ on the left. (If it did not, don't -- but please let me know how to improve my answer).

Comment: Ow, I am sorry, I have forgotten about it :(